# Precision / Recall for multi-label classification using torchmetrics

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Is there a function or a set of arguments that I can use in order to calculate Precision and Recall for a multi-label problem?

Note that with multi-label I mean that each sample can be classified into more than one class.

The following is not returning what I would expect:

```
import torch
from torchmetrics import Precision
target = torch.tensor([
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],  # Sample 1 belongs to class 2 and 3 (zero-indexed)
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], # Sample 2 belongs to class 2 (zero-indexed)
])
preds = torch.tensor([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # Sample 1 predicted to belong to no class
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # Sample 2 predicted to belong to no class
])
metric = Precision(num_classes=5, mdmc_average="samplewise")
print(metric(preds, target))
```

It returns: `tensor(0.7000)`, but it should be 0% since there are no True Positives.

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/classification.html), you can get the multilabel metric by using `multiclass=False`, but it looks like default `average="micro"` doesn't work with `mdmc_average="samplewise"`.  Would `average=None` or `average="macro"` be appropriate for your case?  E.g. `Precision(num_classes=5, multiclass=False, average="macro", mdmc_average="samplewise")`. (I'm not sure I fully grasp the intent of `mdmc_average` in your example, so this might not make sense in your case.)